# How to add noise to existing gates in Cirq?

Tags: cirq, noise

I would like to add noise to existing gates in Cirq, i.e. to define something like

```
NewGate = cirq.Gate(qubit)
```

followed by

```
cirq.DepolarizingChannel(p).on(qubit)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

One simple way to do it is by defining a composite gate, like this:

```
class MyGateThenDepolarize(cirq.SingleQubitGate):
    def _decompose_(self, qubits):
        q = qubits[0]
        return [MyGate.on(q), cirq.depolarize(p).on(q)]
```

If you want a depolarizing gate on every qubit at the end of every moment, you can do a noisy simulation:

```
cirq.sample(circuit, noise=cirq.depolarize(p))
```

Or get a noisy version of the circuit:

```
circuit = circuit.with_noise(cirq.depolarize(p))
```

If you specifically want a noise model that depolarizes the one gate, you can define a custom noise model that does that:

```
class MyGateDepolarizingNoiseModel(cirq.NoiseModel):
    def noisy_operation(self, op):
        if isinstance(op.gate, MyGate):
            return [op, cirq.depolarize(p).on(op.qubits[0])]
        return op
```

And here's a test confirming that it works:

```
import cirq

def test_custom_noise_model():
    p = 0.1

    class MyGate(cirq.Gate):
        def _num_qubits_(self):
            return 1
        def _decompose_(self, qubits):
            return cirq.X(*qubits)

    class MyGateDepolarizingNoiseModel(cirq.NoiseModel):
        def noisy_operation(self, op):
            if isinstance(op.gate, MyGate):
                return [op, cirq.depolarize(p).on(op.qubits[0])]
            return op

    a, b = cirq.LineQubit.range(2)
    c = cirq.Circuit(
        MyGate().on(a),
        cirq.X.on(b),
        cirq.measure(a, key='a'),
        cirq.measure(b, key='b'),
    )
    results = cirq.sample(
        c,
        noise=MyGateDepolarizingNoiseModel(),
        repetitions=1000)
    assert sum(results.data['a']) < 1000  # yes depolarized
    assert sum(results.data['b']) == 1000  # not depolarized

    print(results.data['a'].value_counts())
    # 1    942
    # 0     58
    # Name: a, dtype: int64

    print(results.data['b'].value_counts())
    # 1    1000
    # Name: b, dtype: int64
```