# Simulating noise of googles quantum computers

Tags: qiskit, programming, noise, ibm-quantum-devices, google-sycamore

Is there a way to simulate the noise of googles quantum computers using circ? In the same way that any of IBM's computers can be simulated using different backends?

```
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmqx2')
noise_model = NoiseModel.from_backend(backend)
```

Ideally I would want something like above which allows me to easily call the noise properties of for example Bristlecone or Sycamore.

If this is not possible does anyone know the best way to approach simulating the noise of any of googles quantum computers in qiskit?

I am asking because I wish to compare Google and IBMs quantum computers for implementing a simple circuit.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible from looing at here:
https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/tree/master/cirq/devices
and
https://cirq.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/cirq.NoiseModel.html

---

Also look at these answers on how to implement noise:

1. [How to add noise to existing gates in Cirq?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8661/how-to-add-noise-to-existing-gates-in-cirq)
2. https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/issues/1704

Comment: Okay thanks for this! Is there no way to do something similar to IBM and for example choose to simulate a circuit using the noise model of Bristlecone or Sycamore? I ask because I am trying to draw a comparison between IBMs computers and googles. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any documentation on that, but let see if someone from Cirq will be able to confirm this.  If they do have "nose_model" from the real device, then I would like to use it to run the "Quantum Volume" metric calculation to benchmark their processors with those from IBM and Honeywell. I have not been able to find any "Quantum Volume" metric calculations from the Google quantum computing team on their processors.